# .NET Regex look behind issue

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex:

```
(?<=(url\(.+))\)
```

It supposed to match the closing `)` of `url(`. It works. But if I have any other `)` after the first one, in the same line, it matches too. Example:

```
      url(abc) format(def)
matches this ^  and this ^
```

I would like to know what can be done to match only the `)` char that closes `url(`.

Comment: did you want to match only `abc`?

Comment: @AvinashRaj nope, only `)`, actually. But only the one who closes the `url(`.

Comment: you mean this http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/18

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes but Vache already answered it. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Match for characters that are not `)` instead of any character in your look-behind.

```
(?<=(url\([^)]+))\)
```

Your original regex finds a `)` preceded by the string `abc) format(def` which is itself preceded by `url(` so the second `)` was also valid.